# PHP: Transparent background

Tags: php, transparent, imagecreatefrompng

```
$c = 'johnny-bravo.png'; //transparent bg
$imagesize = getimagesize($c);

$background = imagecreatefrompng('background.png'); //background
$char = imagecreatefrompng($c);

imagealphablending($char, false);
imagesavealpha($char, true);

imagecopymerge($background, $char, 260, 17, 0, 0, $imagesize[0], $imagesize[1], 100);

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($background);
imagedestroy($background);
```

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E7Lz.png

How can I make transparent background to "johnny-bravo" ?

Comment: Don't forget to set the alpha options on the $background image as well.

Comment: @MarcB Done with the "$background" but still same output

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
$c = 'johnny-bravo.png'; //transparent bg
$imagesize = getimagesize($c);

$tmp = @imagecreatetruecolor( $imagesize[0],  $imagesize[1] );
@imagealphablending( $tmp , false );
@imagesavealpha( $tmp , true );
$background = @imagecreatefrompng('background.png');

@imagecopyresampled( $tmp , $background , 0 , 0 , $imagesize[0] , $imagesize[1] , $imagesize[0] , $imagesize[1] );
$char = @imagecreatefrompng($c);
@imagecopyresampled($tmp , $char, 260, 17, 0, 0, $imagesize[0], $imagesize[1], 100);

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp);
```

Comment: @Daniela Răducanu Test My Edited Code

Comment: @Daniela Răducanu you must first create an image to your size, and use `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` after, copy 2 images with `imagecopyresampled` on it, this is your solution, but because i can't access to php web server, can't give to you working code